# Utilize specific video adapter for linux console login

Tags: linux, login, console

My current system has a dedicated video card (DL380G6) for Xwindows/booting up.  This leaves the built in video card (ES1000) unused.  Is there any way to configure it so a text login console is accessible by this video output?  I suppose I would need to bind a specific keyboard or port to it.  The unit does have a PS2 keyboard and USB keyboard.  What I would like to do is bind the PS2 keyboard to the console login on the ES1000 internal video port and the USB keyboard used for Xwindows monitor.  In searching I read about FBCON and it's uses, but this soudns like just for redirecting text output to read.  Does anyone know of a way to achieve a dedicated console login via specified keyboard and display adapter?